# How can I cast a StringCol to an IntCol in krangl?

Tags: dataframe, kotlin, data-science

I am trying to summarize some data in `krangl`, with some numeric data being stored in a `StringCol`, due to missing places being read improperly. After filtering out all the actual `String`s I am now trying to summarize my data using

```kotlin
sq
    .filterByRow {
        it["hw"] as String != "*" // Remove asterisks, they mark missing data we don't need
    }
    .summarize(
        "min_hw" to { it["hw"].min() } // Get the minimum value of the hw column
    )
```

Which fails due to the fact that "hw" is a StringCol, not an IntCol, with the following error:

```
krangl.InvalidColumnOperationException: StringCol is not a supported by this operation 
krangl.ColumnsKt.min(Columns.kt:529)
krangl.ColumnsKt.min$default(Columns.kt:525)
...
```

My question here is: **how can I cast a StringCol to an IntCol** (or any other type of DataCol) **in krangl?**
Any kind of help or point to documentation is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem.  My CSV data includes a `double` column with a space char for missing values. But they should've used zero.  Krangl typed it as a StringCol.  I wrote this extension method, which lets me convert the `StringCol` into a number type.

```
    fun DataFrame.replaceColumn(columnName: String, expression: TableExpression): DataFrame {

        val target: Pair<Int,DataCol> = this.cols.mapIndexed { index, dataCol ->
             if(dataCol.name == columnName) { Pair(index,dataCol) } else null
        }.filterNotNull().first()

        val newCol = this.addColumn(columnName+"_temp", expression).cols.last()

        val mutableCols = this.cols.toMutableList()
        mutableCols.set(target.first, newCol)

        return dataFrameOf( *(mutableCols.toTypedArray())).rename(columnName+"_temp" to columnName)
    }
```

Here's how to call it:

```
df.replaceColumn("my-col") { it["my-col"].map<String>{ if (it == null || it.isEmpty()) 0 else it.toInt() } }
```

This works for me, but I only have a small amount of data.  Please improve this answer if you know a better way.